# Is there a selector for 'between any 2 elements'

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like the input when checked to cause the div (any div) that comes after the div.container to have a border style. I am not sure if there is some combination of elements and selectors that would cause the input when checked to style an element out of range of the input. It seems like I have to rearrange the html but I need the labels (and I suppose the inputs) to be in an enclosing div because I would like the labels to be position:sticky. I've simplified the markup.  This is the css selector rule that is the concern - "html body div  > * ~ *:checked ~ * ~ * ~ * ~ *" . Really it would be simpler if there were a 'anything between 2 selectors' combinator.    I would like when the 2nd input is checked for the content2 div (div.d2) to have a a border of big yellow dots.

```
  html body div  > * ~ *:checked ~ * ~ * ~ * ~ * {
    border:dotted 10px #ff0 !important;;
}
```

Here is the test html - https://jsfiddle.net/gayf9vr6/.

Comment: Like this?  `html body div *:checked ~ * ~ * ~ *  {`

Comment: interesting - that selector causes the inputs to select the labels. I want to select div.d2.

Comment: input and div are inside 2 different parents, CSS cannot select a parent nor a previous sibbling. You need to rethink your html structure or use javascript. :(

Comment: I was just about to say the same. without knowing which item you've clicked, there is no way to tell css what to do.

Comment: here is a possible idea : https://jsfiddle.net/ypgf3xjm/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ypgf3xjm/2/ ?  :(

Comment: Thanks G-Cyrillus - that seems to work. The inputs can extend beyond their parents I think. So the comment from Mech seems partial.

Comment: Oh dear seems like you altered the html. The enclosing div of div.container is missing in jsfiddle.net/ypgf3xjm/1  - so the div.container envelopes the labels,inputs and the divs. It might give me further ideas.